# Understanding Class Values (Translating hexadecimal to decimal)

Tags: python, class, hex

Reading through a simple class and objects chapter online and need help on the follow simple exercise:

> As an exercise, create and print a Point object, and then use id to print the object's unique identifier. Translate the hexadecimal form into decimal and confirm that they match.

I have the following code for the answer:

```
class Point:
    pass

blank = Point()

a = hex(id(blank))
print(a)
print(blank)

if a in repr(blank):
    print("This is true")
```

I get the following output:

```
0x11be830
<__main__.Point object at 0x011BE830>
```

Why are these values not the same?

Comment: Are you referring to `0x11be830` vs `0x011BE830` or that `print(blank)` is more than just the id?

Comment: …they _are_ the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
if a.upper() in repr(blank).upper():
    print("This is true")
```